# Symfony2 No route found for GET ofiler or GET nfigurator

Tags: php, symfony, routes

I have just installed Symfony2 and created my bundle. I removed the Acme demo bundle and tested my new route `"/"` which worked fine.

I then went to **config.php** and followed the link to **_configurator** and get the above route error. I also get the same error when trying to load **_profiler**.

Here is my route file:

```
asf_core_homepage:
    pattern:  /
    defaults: { _controller: ASFCoreBundle:Home:index }
```

And the Symfony routing_dev file:

```
_wdt:
    resource: "@WebProfilerBundle/Resources/config/routing/wdt.xml"
    prefix:   /_wdt

_profiler:
    resource: "@WebProfilerBundle/Resources/config/routing/profiler.xml"
    prefix:   /_profiler

_configurator:
    resource: "@SensioDistributionBundle/Resources/config/routing/webconfigurator.xml"
    prefix:   /_configurator

_main:
    resource: routing.yml
```

Any ideas why this is happening?

**EDIT**

I have narrowed it down and it looks like it has nothing to do with symfony. I have it installed in a subfolder of root so I use htaccess to rewrite all requests from **/forum** to **/forum/web**

`RewriteRule forum/(.*) /forum/web/$1 [L]`

If I point the browser to **/forum/app_dev.php** it works fine. the error comes from **/forum/app_dev.php/_configurator**

But if I skip the rewrite rule and use **/forum/web/app_dev.php/_configurator** it works fine.

Comment: **ofiler** and **nfigurator** are no typos ? ... the exception message is exactly the one in the headline?

Comment: Yes that is the exact exception. It removes 3 characters from the beginning of the route for some reason. Namely **_pr** and **_co**

Comment: And you copy-pasted the routing config and aren't using something freaky like backslashes instead of forward-slashes for your urls? :) Try wrapping the urls in `"/_profiler"`. Further make sure your `routing.yml` file is utf-8 encoded + doesn't contain a BOM. Clear your cache `app/console cache:clear`. If that still doesn't help ... remove all other routes (i.e. the `_main` resource) from the `routing_dev.yml` file and add them one by one (by hand!) . Start with a single route (i.e. `_configurator` ) and if it works: add more ... one-by-one.

Comment: I removed all rules apart from _configurator and enclosed the prefix in quotes `"_configurator"` but I still get the exception. The file doesn't contain a BOM. I have also cleared cache via console and deleted the dev folder from cache just to make sure.

Comment: Added an edit to explain why it may not be Symfony's fault :P